# Passing an array to a function parameter and getting values from nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I got stuck while practicing credit card checker practice.
[image]

My code:

```
// All valid credit card numbers
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8]
const valid2 = [5, 5, 3, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 8, 7, 5, 1, 4, 3, 9]
const valid3 = [3, 7, 1, 6, 1, 2, 0, 1, 9, 9, 8, 5, 2, 3, 6]
const valid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 0, 6, 8, 2, 9, 0, 5]
const valid5 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 4, 0, 4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 6, 9, 6, 6, 6]

// All invalid credit card numbers
const invalid1 = [4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 1, 0, 9, 1, 7, 9, 5]
const invalid2 = [5, 7, 9, 5, 5, 9, 3, 3, 9, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3]
const invalid3 = [3, 7, 5, 7, 9, 6, 0, 8, 4, 4, 5, 9, 9, 1, 4]
const invalid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 9, 6, 1, 7, 7, 7, 9, 3, 5]
const invalid5 = [5, 3, 8, 2, 0, 1, 9, 7, 7, 2, 8, 8, 3, 8, 5, 4]

// Can be either valid or invalid
const mystery1 = [3, 4, 4, 8, 0, 1, 9, 6, 8, 3, 0, 5, 4, 1, 4]
const mystery2 = [5, 4, 6, 6, 1, 0, 0, 8, 6, 1, 6, 2, 0, 2, 3, 9]
const mystery3 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 3, 7, 7, 0, 2, 0, 9, 6, 2, 6, 5, 6, 2, 0, 3]
const mystery4 = [4, 9, 2, 9, 8, 7, 7, 1, 6, 9, 2, 1, 7, 0, 9, 3]
const mystery5 = [4, 9, 1, 3, 5, 4, 0, 4, 6, 3, 0, 7, 2, 5, 2, 3]

// An array of all the arrays above
const batch = [valid1, valid2, valid3, valid4, valid5, invalid1, invalid2, invalid3, invalid4, invalid5, mystery1, mystery2, mystery3, mystery4, mystery5]


// Add your functions below:
const validateCred = (array)=> {
  let tempArrSub = []; //Holds values of the 9 subtracted from doubled elements bigger than 9
  let tempArr = array; //Copies the values of the array passed into parameters
  tempArr.pop();
  tempArr.reverse();

  for (let i = tempArr.length-1; i >=0; i-=2){ //Doubles every two elements from right to left
    tempArr[i] *= 2;
  }

  for (let k = 0; k < tempArr.length; k++) { //Subtract 9 from every second element (right to left) if bigger than 9
    if (tempArr[k] > 9){
      tempArrSub.push(tempArr[k] - 9);
    }
    else {
      tempArrSub.push(tempArr[k]);
    }
  }

  let tempArrSum = 0;

  for (let m = 0; m < tempArrSub.length; m++){ //Calculates the sum of all elements in the array
    tempArrSum += tempArrSub[m];
  }

  tempArrSum += array.pop(); //Adds the last digit of initial array to the sum

  if (tempArrSum % 10 === 0) { //Returns true if the sum is divisible by 10
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }

} //End Of Function


const findInvalidCards = (nestedArray) => {
  let invalidCards = [];
  let validCards = [];
  for (let a = 0; a < nestedArray.length; a++){

    if ( validateCred(nestedArray[a]) == true ) {
      validCards.push(nestedArray[a]);
    }
    else {
      invalidCards.push(nestedArray[a]);
    }
  }

  console.log("Invalid cards: \n" + invalidCards);
  console.log("Valid cards: \n" + validCards);
}
```

I checked all arrays one by one passing as an argument to validateCred() function. It's working and returning true or false for each credit card.

In order to automate process I wanted findInvalidCards() to find valid or invalid cards by calling validateCred() function inside itself and returning boolean value for each card.

Here I got stuck. Because it is returning true for the 1st card and false for the remaining cards. I've been playing with the code for the whole day, but I could not move forward. I rely on your help. Thanks in advance

Comment: _"`tempArr = array; //Copies the values`"_ this just makes both variables reference the same array object, it is not a copy. So `tempArr.pop();`, and `array.pop()` further down, are altering the original array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if is it helpful to you or not. But I rewrite your code with an optimal way.

```
// All valid credit card numbers
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8]
const valid2 = [5, 5, 3, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 8, 7, 5, 1, 4, 3, 9]
const valid3 = [3, 7, 1, 6, 1, 2, 0, 1, 9, 9, 8, 5, 2, 3, 6]
const valid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 0, 6, 8, 2, 9, 0, 5]
const valid5 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 4, 0, 4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 6, 9, 6, 6, 6]

// All invalid credit card numbers
const invalid1 = [4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 1, 0, 9, 1, 7, 9, 5]
const invalid2 = [5, 7, 9, 5, 5, 9, 3, 3, 9, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3]
const invalid3 = [3, 7, 5, 7, 9, 6, 0, 8, 4, 4, 5, 9, 9, 1, 4]
const invalid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 9, 6, 1, 7, 7, 7, 9, 3, 5]
const invalid5 = [5, 3, 8, 2, 0, 1, 9, 7, 7, 2, 8, 8, 3, 8, 5, 4]

// Can be either valid or invalid
const mystery1 = [3, 4, 4, 8, 0, 1, 9, 6, 8, 3, 0, 5, 4, 1, 4]
const mystery2 = [5, 4, 6, 6, 1, 0, 0, 8, 6, 1, 6, 2, 0, 2, 3, 9]
const mystery3 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 3, 7, 7, 0, 2, 0, 9, 6, 2, 6, 5, 6, 2, 0, 3]
const mystery4 = [4, 9, 2, 9, 8, 7, 7, 1, 6, 9, 2, 1, 7, 0, 9, 3]
const mystery5 = [4, 9, 1, 3, 5, 4, 0, 4, 6, 3, 0, 7, 2, 5, 2, 3]

// An array of all the arrays above
const batch = [valid1, valid2, valid3, valid4, valid5, invalid1, invalid2, invalid3, invalid4, invalid5, mystery1, mystery2, mystery3, mystery4, mystery5];

isValidCard = (array) => {
  let copy = [...array];
  const last = copy.pop();
  copy.reverse();
  copy = copy.map((dig, i) => ((i % 2 === 0 ? dig * 2 : dig)));
  copy = copy.map(dig => (dig > 9 ? dig - 9 : dig));
  const sum = copy.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr);

  return ((sum + last) % 10 === 0);
}

findInvalidCards = (array) => {
  const validList = [];
  const invalidList = [];

  array.forEach(card => {
      if (isValidCard(card)) {
        validList.push(card);
      } else {
        invalidList.push(card);
      }
  });

  console.log('valid cards', validList);
  console.log('invalid cards', invalidList);
}

findInvalidCards(batch);
```

Comment: copy = copy.map((dig, i) => ((i % 2 === 0 ? dig * 2 : dig))); Do you multiply even numbers by 2 with this method?

Comment: Nope! The index starts from 0. So the index number 2 is an odd index.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is this line:

```
let tempArr = array; //Copies the values of the array passed into parameters
```

According to your comment you want to copy the array, but just assigning it to another variable does not copies it. In order to copy just so something like this:

```
let copy = array.slice(0);
/* or (will not work for large arrays)  */
let copy = [...array];
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
// All valid credit card numbers
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];
const valid2 = [5, 5, 3, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 8, 7, 5, 1, 4, 3, 9];
const valid3 = [3, 7, 1, 6, 1, 2, 0, 1, 9, 9, 8, 5, 2, 3, 6];
const valid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 0, 6, 8, 2, 9, 0, 5];
const valid5 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 4, 0, 4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 6, 9, 6, 6, 6];

// All invalid credit card numbers
const invalid1 = [4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 1, 0, 9, 1, 7, 9, 5];
const invalid2 = [5, 7, 9, 5, 5, 9, 3, 3, 9, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3];
const invalid3 = [3, 7, 5, 7, 9, 6, 0, 8, 4, 4, 5, 9, 9, 1, 4];
const invalid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 9, 6, 1, 7, 7, 7, 9, 3, 5];
const invalid5 = [5, 3, 8, 2, 0, 1, 9, 7, 7, 2, 8, 8, 3, 8, 5, 4];
const invalidCredit = [invalid1, invalid2, invalid3, invalid4, invalid5]
// Can be either valid or invalid
const mystery1 = [3, 4, 4, 8, 0, 1, 9, 6, 8, 3, 0, 5, 4, 1, 4];
const mystery2 = [5, 4, 6, 6, 1, 0, 0, 8, 6, 1, 6, 2, 0, 2, 3, 9];
const mystery3 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 3, 7, 7, 0, 2, 0, 9, 6, 2, 6, 5, 6, 2, 0, 3];
const mystery4 = [4, 9, 2, 9, 8, 7, 7, 1, 6, 9, 2, 1, 7, 0, 9, 3];
const mystery5 = [4, 9, 1, 3, 5, 4, 0, 4, 6, 3, 0, 7, 2, 5, 2, 3];

// An array of all the arrays above
const batch = [valid1, valid2, valid3, valid4, valid5, invalid1, invalid2, invalid3, invalid4, invalid5, mystery1, mystery2, mystery3, mystery4, mystery5];


// Add your functions below:
const validateCred = (arr) => {

  let reversedArr = arr.reverse();
  let oddOccurrences = [];


  reversedArr.forEach((value, i) => i % 2 ? oddOccurrences.push(value *= 2) : oddOccurrences.push(value));


  const checking = oddOccurrences.map((greater) => (greater > 9 ? (greater -= 9) : greater));


  const sum = checking.reduce((acc, num) => {
    return acc + num
  }, 0)

  // Conditional check
  if (sum % 10 === 0)
    return 'valid'
  else return 'invalid'

}

console.log(validateCred([4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 8, 9, 8, 8, 7, 7, 0, 5, 7, 9, 8]));




findInvalidCards = (newArr) => {
  const invalidList = [];
  const validList = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < newArr.length; i += 15) {
    // inner loop
    for (let j = 0; j < newArr.length; j++) {
      validateCred(newArr[j]) === 'invalid' ? invalidList.push(newArr[j]) : validList.push(newArr[j]);
    }
  };
  console.log(invalidList)
}

findInvalidCards(batch);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).